# Animated GIFs not working in Chrome v62

Tags: google-chrome, gif, animated-gif

Many animated GIF images are not working in Chrome v62. The same images work fine in Firefox and IE. For example, the below image loads 4 frames correctly and then disappears in Chrome v62. In other browsers, it will loop forever showing all 5 frames. This image worked fine on Chrome v61.

[image]

Comment: It seems to have been fixed in 64, and simply opening it in PS and reexporting it as is make it work in 62. Probably this one: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=786156&can=1&q=gif%20label%3AM62&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. Yes, this is the bug affecting my application. Is there a way to fix this issue without using Photoshop ? I am generating the image in PHP.